Prove that $E\left[\,{\left\vert\,{g(X)+g(Y)}\,\right\vert}\,\rule{0pt}{4mm}\right] \geq E[|g(Y)|]$
Let $X, Y$ be two independent random variables, both uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$ and let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $  be continuous function. Does following inequality always hold?
$E\left[\,{\left\vert\,{g(X)+g(Y)}\,\right\vert}\,\rule{0pt}{4mm}\right] \geq E[|g(Y)|]$
I think this is more calculus problem, as this inequality can be rewritten in the following way:
$\int_0^1\int_0^1|g(x)+g(y)|dxdy \geq \int_0^1|g(y)|dy$
It is easy to show that
$\int_0^1\int_0^1(g(x)+g(y))^2dxdy\geq \int_0^1g(y)^2dy$
but I don't know how to derive initial inequality.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Please, use descriptive titles.

The inequality is true. It is an old problem.

See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016141/the-weighted-average-absolute-value-of-pairwise-sum-of-any-finite-sequence-is-la/4016986#4016986, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73945/stuck-trying-to-prove-an-inequality, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507930/how-prove-this-inequality-sum-i-j-1nx-ix-j-ge-n-sum-i-1nx
